# Is there a way to make the lightning-input placeholder text appear smaller

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightninginput

I'd like to make the placeholder text to appear smaller in the lightning-input component. Is it possible? and if yes, how can I achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot affect the inner elements of a component, so there is no supported workaround. You would need to write your own component, instead, which is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you, sir!